# Query HDF5 in Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I have following data (18,619,211 rows) stored as a pandas dataframe object in hdf5 file:

```
             date    id2         w
id                              
100010 1980-03-31   10401  0.000839
100010 1980-03-31   10604  0.020140
100010 1980-03-31   12490  0.026149
100010 1980-03-31   13047  0.033560
100010 1980-03-31   13303  0.001657
```

where `id` is index and others are columns. `date` is `np.datetime64`. I need to perform query like this (the code doesn't work of course):

```
db=pd.HDFStore('database.h5')
data=db.select('df', where='id==id_i & date>bgdt & date<endt')
```

Note `id_i, bgdt, endt` are all variables, not actual values and need to be passed within a loop. for example:

`dates` is a Pandas Period index or timestamps index, either way, I can convert to each other.

```
dates=['1990-01', 1990-04','1990-09',......]
```

`id_list` is a list of IDs

```
id_list=[100010, 100011,1000012,.......]
```

The loop looks like this (the reason I am doing loop is because the data is huge, there are other datasets I have query in the same time and then perform some operations)

```
db=pd.HDFStore('database.h5')
for id_i in id_list:
    for date in dates:
        bgdt=date-1 (move to previous month)
        endt=date-60 (previous 60 month)
        data=db.select('df', where='index==id_i & date>bgdt & date<endt')
        ......
```

This problem have 2 parts:

- I don't know how to query index and columns in the same time. The doc in pandas showed how to query based on index conditions OR columns conditions, but no examples on how to query based on them in the SAME TIME.

  - (BTW, This is very common in Pandas Documentation. The doc usually shows very simple thing like how to do 'A', OR how to do 'B', but not how to do BOTH 'A' and 'B'. A good example is use `query` on a MultiIndex pandas dataframe. The doc shows based on either `level=0` OR `level=1`, but no example on how to do BOTH in the SAME TIME.)
- I don't know how to pass three variables `id_i, bgdt, endt` to the query. I know how to pass only on by using `%s`, but not all of them.

  - I am also a little confused with the datetime datatype. There seems to be quite a few of datetimes:`datetime.datetime`, `numpy.datetime64`, `pandas.Period`. I am mostly working on monthly data, so `pandas.Period` is the most useful one. But I can't easily convert a column (not index) of timestamps (the default date type of Pandas when parsed from raw data). Is there any datatype that is simply a 'date', not timestamps, not period, but just a simple DATE with only year,month and day?

A lot troubles, but I really LOVE python and pandas (I am trying to move my workflow from SAS to Python). Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: you say you are doing this in a loop; well give an example of what you are doing then, eg what separate queries you are doing (with actual values); and why are you looping ?

Comment: @Jeff ,I just edited the question to give an example of loop. The reason I am looping is to avoid reading a huge amount data into memory. I am just giving a minor example, the real operation needs to query a few of such datasets, impossible to fit into memory.

Comment: show ptdump -av <file.h5> as well; looking to see what u have defined as data columns

Comment: Hi @jeff, first I don't know how to do it .... second, I don't think that will help

Comment: well you type "ptdump -av file.h5" and post the output in your question; showing more information is always better (and this does matter); this is a script that PyTables installs

Comment: Well @jeff, I don't know what you are looking for, but my df5 file contains only 1 pandas dataframe as described in the beginning of question. It was written by db.append('df',df).

Comment: pls review these docs: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#query-via-data-columns; you can only query designated columns; more data will help me give u a better answer. pls post the lengths of unique ids/dates u want to retrieve, as well as the range of dates in your set. best would be to post df.head() and df.tail()

Comment: Or put it simply, could you please show a example of querying based on index and columns in the mean time from a dataframe stored in hdf5 file? Many thanks.

Comment: When I pass a query like this `test=db.select('df', 'index=%d & date<%r' %(funds[1], pd.Timestamp('1990-01-06')))` (where `date` is a column of `df` and `index` is just the index of `df`.  I have following error message: `ValueError: The passed where expression: index=100003 & date<Timestamp('1990-01-06 00:00:00', tz=None)
            contains an invalid variable reference
            all of the variable refrences must be a reference to
            an axis (e.g. 'index' or 'columns'), or a data_column
            The currently defined references are: index,columns`

Comment: I posted an answer. The doc reference I pointed explains that you need to create the store with ``date`` as a ``data_column``, otherwise it is not-queryable. You can pass ``data_columns=True`` if you really want to make all columns queryable, but for various performance reasons this is not a good idea and is not the default. You have a large dataset and to get best performance it needs to be stored in a logical manner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#query-via-data-columns) are the docs for querying on non-index columns.

Create the test data. It is not clear how the original frame is constructed, e.g. whether its unique data and the ranges, so I have created a sample, with 10M rows, and a multi-level date range with the id column.

```
In [60]: np.random.seed(1234)

In [62]: pd.set_option('display.max_rows',20)

In [63]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([np.arange(10000,11000),pd.date_range('19800101',periods=10000)],names=['id','date'])

In [67]: df = DataFrame(dict(id2=np.random.randint(0,1000,size=len(index)),w=np.random.randn(len(index))),index=index).reset_index().set_index(['id','date'])

In [68]: df
Out[68]: 
                  id2         w
id    date                     
10000 1980-01-01  712  0.371372
      1980-01-02  718 -1.255708
      1980-01-03  581 -1.182727
      1980-01-04  202 -0.947432
      1980-01-05  493 -0.125346
      1980-01-06  752  0.380210
      1980-01-07  435 -0.444139
      1980-01-08  128 -1.885230
      1980-01-09  425  1.603619
      1980-01-10  449  0.103737
...               ...       ...
10999 2007-05-09    8  0.624532
      2007-05-10  669  0.268340
      2007-05-11  918  0.134816
      2007-05-12  979 -0.769406
      2007-05-13  969 -0.242123
      2007-05-14  950 -0.347884
      2007-05-15   49 -1.284825
      2007-05-16  922 -1.313928
      2007-05-17  347 -0.521352
      2007-05-18  353  0.189717

[10000000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Write the data to disk, showing how to create a data column (note that the indexes are automatically queryable, this allows id2 to be queryable as well). This is de-facto equivalent to doing. This takes care of opening and closing the store (you can accomplish the same thing by opening a store, appending, and closing).

In order to query a column, it MUST BE A DATA COLUMN or an index of the frame.

```
In [70]: df.to_hdf('test.h5','df',mode='w',data_columns=['id2'],format='table')

In [71]: !ls -ltr test.h5
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jreback users 430540284 May 26 17:16 test.h5
```

Queries

```
In [80]: ids=[10101,10898]

In [81]: start_date='20010101'

In [82]: end_date='20010301'
```

You can specify dates as string (either in-line or as variables; you can also specify Timestamp like objects)

```
In [83]: pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where='date>start_date & date<end_date')
Out[83]: 
                  id2         w
id    date                     
10000 2001-01-02  972 -0.146107
      2001-01-03  954  1.420412
      2001-01-04  567  1.077633
      2001-01-05   87 -0.042838
      2001-01-06   79 -1.791228
      2001-01-07  744  1.110478
      2001-01-08  237 -0.846086
      2001-01-09  998 -0.696369
      2001-01-10  266 -0.595555
      2001-01-11  206 -0.294633
...               ...       ...
10999 2001-02-19  616 -0.745068
      2001-02-20  577 -1.474748
      2001-02-21  990 -1.276891
      2001-02-22  939 -1.369558
      2001-02-23  621 -0.214365
      2001-02-24  396 -0.142100
      2001-02-25  492 -0.204930
      2001-02-26  478  1.839291
      2001-02-27  688  0.291504
      2001-02-28  356 -1.987554

[58000 rows x 2 columns]
```

You can use in-line lists

```
In [84]: pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where='date>start_date & date<end_date & id=ids')
Out[84]: 
                  id2         w
id    date                     
10101 2001-01-02  722  1.620553
      2001-01-03  849 -0.603468
      2001-01-04  635 -1.419072
      2001-01-05  331  0.521634
      2001-01-06  730  0.008830
      2001-01-07  706 -1.006412
      2001-01-08   59  1.380005
      2001-01-09  689  0.017830
      2001-01-10  788 -3.090800
      2001-01-11  704 -1.491824
...               ...       ...
10898 2001-02-19  530 -1.031167
      2001-02-20  652 -0.019266
      2001-02-21  472  0.638266
      2001-02-22  540 -1.827251
      2001-02-23  654 -1.020140
      2001-02-24  328 -0.477425
      2001-02-25  871 -0.892684
      2001-02-26  166  0.894118
      2001-02-27  806  0.648240
      2001-02-28  824 -1.051539

[116 rows x 2 columns]
```

You can also specify boolean expressions

```
In [85]: pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where='date>start_date & date<end_date & id=ids & id2>500 & id2<600')
Out[85]: 
                  id2         w
id    date                     
10101 2001-01-12  534 -0.220692
      2001-01-14  596 -2.225393
      2001-01-16  596  0.956239
      2001-01-30  513 -2.528996
      2001-02-01  572 -1.877398
      2001-02-13  569 -0.940748
      2001-02-14  541  1.035619
      2001-02-21  571 -0.116547
10898 2001-01-16  591  0.082564
      2001-02-06  586  0.470872
      2001-02-10  531 -0.536194
      2001-02-16  586  0.949947
      2001-02-19  530 -1.031167
      2001-02-22  540 -1.827251
```

To answer your actual question I would do this (their is really not enough information, but I'll put some reasonable expectations):

- Do't loop over queries, unless you have a very small number of absolute queries
- Read the biggest chunk into memory that you can. Usually this is accomplished by selecting out the biggest ranges of data that you need, even if you select MORE data than you actually need.
- Then subselect using in-memory expressions, which will generally be orders of magnitude faster.
- List elements are limited to about 30 elements in total (this is current an implementation limit on the PyTables side). It will work if you specify more, but what will happen is that you will read in a lot of data, then it will be reindexed down (in-memory). So user needs to be aware of this.

So for example say that you have 1000 unique ids with 10000 dates per as my example demonstrates. You want to select say 200 of these, with a date range of 1000.

So in this case I would simply select on the dates then do the in-memory comparison, something like this:

```
df = pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where='date=>global_start_date & date<=global_end_date')
df[df.isin(list_of_ids)]
```

You also might have dates that change per ids. So chunk them, this time using a list of ids.

Something like this:

```
output = []
for i in len(list_of_ids) % 30:
    ids = list_of_ids[i:(i+30)]
    start_date = get_start_date_for_these_ids (global)
    end_date = get_end_date_for_these_ids (global)
    where = 'id=ids & start_date>=start_date & end_date<=end_date'
    df = pd.read_hdf('test.h5','df',where=where)
    output.append(df)

 final_result = concat(output)
```

The basic idea then is to select a superset of the data using the criteria that you want, sub-selecting so it fits in memory, but you limit the number of queries you do (e.g. imagine that you end up selecting a single row with your query, if you have to query this 18M times that is bad).

Comment: Thank you so much for input! I did what you showed me, but still got error. I posted as an answer as it's too long for a comment. Could you take a look at the error message? Thank you!